# Organization vs. Board

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I'm still not clear on the difference between Organizations and Boards.  I understand they are a form of hierarchy, but it seems we must repeatedly assign members to each organization, then again to the Board and once again to each Card.

As far as I can see:

1. Members of an organization can only SEE the boards, cards, etc., but not allowed to make any changes, comments, etc.
2. Members of the Organization must then be added as members to each Board, which still does not allow them to make any changes to the board, cards, etc.
3. Once members of the organization are added as members of a card, then they can finally interact...

Unfortunately, I have not seen anything in the help documentation which streamlines the process.  I realize you are leaving it open to be used as each individual or group likes to use it, but the interaction between the various levels of the hierarchy (Organization, Board, Card) is not clear without lots of trial and error...

We have different companies being managed from one office and I wouldn't want certain members to even see the boards or cards associated with another company (organization).  So it seems the organization can be the various groupings of individuals who can have access to the boards and cards of that group, with various levels of permissions, etc...

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An Organization (org) is a group of people (resources) in a company.

A Board is similar to a Project that has cards (tasks) handled by resources (people)

When you create an Org add all the people associated with that company that will be working on the projects.  You can create as many orgs as you like.

The key is setting up the boards Visibility correctly.  When you setup a new board make sure it is associated with an org and not just a general none or private board.  This is key so all Org members can find and join boards that are listed in that org.  This is how you can setup multiple orgs without members seeing the other org's boards.

Most likely you have setup new boards but not set them to an organization.  That is why you have to keep adding members.  Note that boards will not automatically add everyone to an otg's board but they can at least add themselves.  When they add themselves to the board they can then edit cards, etc. (IF you have board edit options set to allow editing)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.  It is now clearer for me how these functions interact with each other.

Comment: Since we can make an org visible to only people who are invited, does it make sense to have all members in an org and then make each board visible to the members of the org we want to keep the board limited to?  I assume uninvited members would not be able to see the board they're not invited to.  Alternatively, I assume we can make orgs around groups of people whom we want to give access to a certain set of boards rather than one group for each company? _Sorry, couldn't insert line breaks.  Comment was posted after a "return"_.

Comment: You can treat an Org as a team, selecting only the members you wish.

Comment: When you create boards make sure they are only visible to the org (team members) you wish to allow.  Remember to use both Organization and Visibility settings to manage who can find and join the board.  Org members can join a board if the settings are visible to the Organization.   Private boards are for when you want to specifically invite only certain members. @Raminmo

Comment: Thanks for all your help and advice.  Will get working on it and plan something.  I am concerned I will end up with too many orgs.  Is there a way to consolidate the various orgs into one screen so I can see all that I have to track personally?  Otherwise, maybe the idea of one big org with many members and different visibilities and privacy settings would be the way to go. Can you think of any example you can direct me to (public orgs or boards)?  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Raminmo Click on the top right icon that represents you or your initials.  Click on Boards to see the list broken out by org.  In the end it might just be easier add once the names you want to private boards, depending on how many people you have.   As to public boards, visit the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) and [Trello Resources Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-resources/4f84a60f0cbdcb7e7d40e099) for examples of how [FogCreek](https://trello.com/fogcreek) uses Trello.